# Access Laravel Environment variable in React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel

I have a Laravel Application where I am using React Components in some of my views. I am using "axios" in a component to make an HTTP request. I need to access an API KEY in component which is stored in Laravel's '.env' file. Currently I have a component 'http.js' which has the key. Here is my code.

http.js

```
import axios from "axios"

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: window.location.origin + "/api/",
    headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/octet-stream",
        "Authorization": "Bearer 12345"
    },

})
```

main.js

```
import http from "./http"

http.post("generate/downloadReport", formData, {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
            },
            responseType: 'blob',
            processData: false,
        }).then(response => {
            this.setState({
                downloadLoading: false
            })
        })
```

In short, main.js is using http.js to make API call. What I need is to access Laravel environment variable in http.js to set API key.

Thanks

Comment: The React app is running in your users' browsers, and (hopefully!) has no access to the server-side environment.

Comment: Is there a way to pass or access the API KEY in react component somehow? I can pass it to my blade view but I cant to React Component.

Answer (score 0):

I used sessionStorage object to pass API key from Laravel to React.
I made the following changes.

http.js

```
import axios from "axios"

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: window.location.origin + "/api/",
    headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/octet-stream",
    },

})
```

main.js

```
import http from "./http"

constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
    api_token: sessionStorage.getItem('api_key')
   }
}

http.post("generate/downloadReport", formData, {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
                "Authorization": this.state.api_token
            },
            responseType: 'blob',
            processData: false,
        }).then(response => {
            this.setState({
                downloadLoading: false
            })
        })
```

Laravel Controller.php

```
$api_key = config('app.api_key');
return view('layouts.report.index',compact('api_key'));
```

Laravel view.blade.php

```
<script>
   //Get api key 
   var api_key = {!! json_encode($api_key) !!};
   //Store it in session storage so that it can be retrieved in React Component
   sessionStorage.setItem('api_key',api_key);
</script>
```

I store the API key in .env file

Thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).